# Promoted links unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am wondering if it is still possible to assign unique permissions to specific promoted links in sharepoint 2016 (on-prem). I have full rights and was made a site collection admin but I still am unable to uniquely assign permissions to one of the 3 promoted links I have setup. The "shared with" is greyed out.[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique permission is still possible, but the option is grayed out on *ITEMS* tab. It seems to be a known issue only in SP16 (also found in another [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c70e92e0-f49e-4953-a200-de2d82fe4d2e/controlling-visibility-of-links-in-a-promoted-links-list?forum=sharepointgeneral)).

As a workaround, you can use the “**Shared With**” option on the **display form**, which is still available and in function.

[image]

Comment: Man you are incredible and this totally helped! I was going insane looking for a solution to this!! Thanks again so much!